# How can I return multiple values like print in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.5

For example, if I use print it gives me 101 238 157 and None.

```
i = 0
while i < 3:
  champion = matchList['matches'][i]['champion']
  i = i + 1
  print(champion)
```

But if I use RETURN it only returns 101.
So what can I do?

Comment: `return` will stop the execution of your while loop (assuming that you actual code is valid and that example is actually in a function) and return the current value of champion. You will either need to collect all values of `champion` that you want in a list or similar _before_ returning the list, or use a generator function and `yield` the results one at a time.

Comment: Gather all results in a list and return the list after the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return can have only one value, (that can be an object like a list or something else)... why? Just because return is the value that assume the function. In the moment you do an assignment of a function for example

```
def champs()
     return MJ KD LBJ

champ = champs()
```

In this way the number should be MJ, KD and LBJ at the same time... impossible conceptually. But we can return a list!

---

First of all use a for loop, is more compact an readable, and do the same things:

```
for i in range(3):
    champion = matchList['matches'][i]['champion']
    print(champion)
```

Now use a list of champions:

```
champions = []
for i in range(3):
    champion = matchList['matches'][i]['champion']
    champions.append(champion)
    print (champion)
```

In a more compact way:

```
champions = []
for i in range(3):
    champions.append(matchList['matches'][i]['champion'])
    print(champions)
```

now you can return it in a func:

```
    def getChamp(matchList):
        champions = []
        for i in range(3):
            champions.append(matchList['matches'][i]['champion'])
        return champions
```

Maybe you would like to make the for loop more dynamic:

```
def getChamp(matchList):
        champions = []
        for match in range(len(matchList['matches'])):
            champions.append(matchList['matches'][match]['champion'])
        return champions
```

This is a more pythonic way

```
def getChamp(matchList):
        for match in matchList['matches']:
            yield match['champion']
        yield None
```

I hope this is what you needed to do!

Comment: Can you please fix your syntax so that it is valid? Your later loops are invalid as well - you iterate over `matches` but still try to index with `i`.

Comment: Now it's operative.

Answer (score 0):

You can either collect all values and `return` them at once, or [`yield` each value one after the other](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator):

```
# initial match list
matchList = {'matches': [{'champion': champ} for champ in (101, 238, 157, None)]}

def all_at_once():
    result = []
    for match in matchList['matches']:
        result.append(match['champion'])
    return result

def one_after_another():
    for match in matchList['matches']:
        yield match['champion']
```

Both of these provide an iterable - you can use them in `for` loops, pass them to `list` or destructure them, for example:

```
for item in one_after_another():
    print(item)

print(*all_at_once())

first, second, third, *rest = one_after_another()
print(first, second, third)
```

---

Since your transformation maps directly from one form to another, you can express both in [comprehension form](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) as well:

```
all_at_once = [match['champion'] for match in matchList['matches']]
one_after_another = (match['champion'] for match in matchList['matches'])
```

---

While both provide iterables, the two are not equivalent. `return` means you build the entire list up front, whereas `yield` lazily computes each value.

```
def print_all_at_once():
    result = []
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        result.append(i)
    return result

def print_one_after_another():
    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        yield i

# prints 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2
for item in print_all_at_once():
    print(item)

# print 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2
for item in print_one_after_another():
    print(item)
```

When you `return` a list, you can also *reuse* its content. In contrast, when you `yield` each value, it is gone after use:

```
returned = print_all_at_once()  # already prints as list is built
print('returned', *returned)  # prints all values
print('returned', *returned)  # still prints all values

yielded = print_one_after_another()  # no print as nothing consumed yet
print('yielded', *yielded)  # prints all values and value generation
print('yielded', *yielded)  # prints no values
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do but the following is simpler way using range and for loop. The data will be a list of your outputs. You may try yeild also

```
data=[matchList['matches'][i]['champion'] for i in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all values ​to one variable and return it.

```
def get_my_value():
    values = []
    for i in range(3):
        champion = matchList['matches'][i]['champion']
        values.append(champion)
    return values

data = get_my_value()
```